# is it possible to do a "where in" query with datamapper?

Tags: ruby, ruby-datamapper

I would like to get a list of objects that match a specified ID from [datamapper](http://datamapper.org/).

I know I could use multiple '**or**' conditions, but the list of id's can be in the hundreds.

Is there a [datamapper](http://datamapper.org/) command that is equivalent to the following sql?

```
select * from table where id in (1,2,3,4,5)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can! It will look something like this:

```
users = User.all(:id => [1,2,3])
```

EDIT: you can see this on the [github page for dm-core](https://github.com/datamapper/dm-core):

```
  # If the value of a pair is an Array, we do an IN-clause for you.
  Person.all(:name.like => 'S%', :id => [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ])

  # Does a NOT IN () clause for you.
  Person.all(:name.not => [ 'bob', 'rick', 'steve' ])
```

Comment: DM monkeypatches Symbol? egads.